# Print JSON Content in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'd like to print this json 
i can print the first part with the actions

**PHP:**

```
$print= json_decode($output_data);

foreach($print->actions as $mydata)
{
    echo $mydata->ID.'<br><br>';
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "ID":"Search",
      "name":"Select"
    }
  ],
  "content": {
    "TEST": "false",
    "nickname": "brad"
  }
}
```

but i cant print the content part to show the TEST and nickname content.

Can you please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: please check and format your JSON, the JSON structure is not right
```{
    "actions":[ 
    {
    "ID":"Search"
    ,"name":"Select"
    ]
    } 
    ,"content":{
    "TEST":"false",
    "nickmane":"brad"

    }```

Comment: Output the correct JSON, cause it's impossible to predict how it looks, and then write a suggested solution to your problem.

Comment: Always put a check to validate the JSON object before iterating it.

Answer (score 0):

In the assumption you Json format is like this:

```
{
  "actions" : [{
      "ID" : "Search",
      "name" : "Select"
    }
  ],
  "content" : {
    "TEST" : "false",
    "nickmane" : "brad"
  }
}
```

You can do it like in next example:

```
$print= json_decode($output_data);

// Print all actions IDs:

foreach($print->actions as $mydata)
{
    echo $mydata->ID . '<br><br>';
}

// Print TEST.

echo "TEST: " . $print->content->TEST . " Nickname: " . $print->content->nickname;
```

Also, if you need to dump all the JSON, try this:

```
$print = json_decode($output_data);
print_r($print);
```

Or this:

```
$print = json_decode($output_data);
$output = print_r($print, true);
echo $output;
```

You can read more about print_r() and other ways to dump variables here: http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php

Comment: i need just the TEST value to be print not all the json

Comment: See the comments on your question, you have errors on the JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite simply like this:

```
$print= json_decode($output_data);
echo $print->content->TEST;
echo "<br/>";
echo $print->content->nickmane;
```

The difference from the "actions" is that "actions" is an array whereas "content" is an object, so you don't need a loop.

[Click here to run a demo of this code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/23ff08da7b25631f5fd0773876ba61ff20f6d3e7)

Answer (score -2):

Your JSON is not a valid format.  I appears your JSON should be the following to do what you want:

```
{
  "actions" : [{
      "ID" : "Search",
      "name" : "Select"
    }
  ],
  "content" : {
    "TEST" : "false",
    "nickmane" : "brad"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that's the correct format. but either way it doesn't answer the actual question. This should probably be a comment.

Comment: this my JSON :{
  "actions" : [{
      "ID" : "Search",
      "name" : "Select"
    }
  ],
  "content" : {
    "TEST" : "false",
    "nickmane" : "brad"
  }
} i need to print the test part thanks for u re help